# using jquery in three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

Thanks again guys for the previous help, but again, I need your help.
Now I have markers on my map, just like I wanted. But, now these markers need to be clickable. In fact, they need to show another div when clicked (so jquery needed).

I have tried it like this:

First, I started with putting my canvas in a div with an id:

```
    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    container.setAttribute("id", "driedkaart");
    document.body.appendChild( container );
```

Then, by adding the markers like this:

```
// ADD SPRITES FOR MARKERS
var pin = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'pin.png' );

var marker = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: pin } );
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( marker );
sprite.position.set( 1.3, 1.9, -1.7 );
sprite.scale.set(0.2, 0.6, 0.5 );

var marker = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: pin } );
var sprite1 = new THREE.Sprite( marker );
sprite1.position.set( -2.3, 1.9, -1.9 );
sprite1.scale.set(0.2, 0.6, 0.5 );

//Group the markers to set them relative to the map

    group = new THREE.Object3D;
    group.add(sprite);
    group.add(sprite1);
    scene.add(group);
```

And now, I want to make them clickable (jquery is linked correctly):

```
    sprite = document.createElement('img');
    sprite.setAttribute("id", "Eersteslagomieper");
    sprite.src = 'pin.png';
    document.body.appendChild(sprite);
```

This creates the img after the canvas. But I need the sprite (on the map) to be clickable.

ps: The marker image isn't set on point just yet, but don't worry about that :)

Thanks again

live code: http://www.bensjitestsite.site50.net

Comment: I already looked into tquery, but when I link the library, it gives a lot of errors (inside the tquery library file), so I'm afraid tquery isn't an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword for clickable objects in three.js is RayCaster.

```
// Projector to generate the 3D coordinates from the click
var projector = new THREE.Projector();

// push all the clickable objects into this array
var clickableObjects = [];    
clickableObjects.push(sprite,sprite1);

// Bind the mousedown handler
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // transforms the 2D click coordinates into a THREE.Vector3 for 3D coordinates
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
            projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

  // casts a ray from the camera position directly to the calculated vector
  var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

  // iterates through the clickable objects and checks if they intersect with the ray
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( clickableObjects );

  if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    // The intersects array contains all the elements,
    // that intersect with the casted ray. intersects[0] is the nearest object.
    console.log('Intersects:',intersects)
  }

}
```

After casting a ray from the camera position to the normalized vector that is calculated with the mouse down event values, you'll get an array of objects that intersect with the casted ray. You can now identify the clicked object and display the needed div.

Comment: isn't this for meshes, particles? I would like it to work on sprites?

Comment: Since THREE.Sprite extends THREE.Object3D, it works the same way. I edited my given example, so you can paste it into your code after you created the sprites.

Comment: Thank you for this, it works (it detects when clicked and puts it in an array). But I don't think it's possible to put an link behind them?

Comment: you can add onClick callbacks to the sprites

   `sprites1.onClick = function(){console.log('Sprite1 got clicked');}`
and in the mousedown callback you do
   `if ( intersects.length > 0 ) { intersects[0].object.onClick(); }`